# How to get refresh token for "Sign In With Google"

Tags: reactjs, express, oauth, google-oauth, sign-in-with-google

I have been trying to create a refresh token since the access token keep on expiring in 1hr.

```
 window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: ,
      callback: handleCredentialResponse,
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("google-signin-button"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large", shape: "circle" } // customization attributes
    );
    google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
  };
```

In this doc from google nothing is mentioned about create a refresh token. https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Anyone help me out thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sign-in` or authentication is login and returns and id token and an access token, and identifies the user behind the machine.

`Oauth2` is authorization and returns an access token and refresh token granting your application access to a users data.

Signin will not return a refresh token.

If you read further on the page you linked you will fined a section intitled [Separated Authentication and Authorization Moments](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview#separated_authentication_and_authorization_moments)

> To obtain an access token for use with Google APIs, or to load some user data, you need to call the [Google Identity Services authorization API](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview) instead. It's a separated JavaScript API, but packaged together with the authentication API.

Solution to your issue is to use [Google Identity Services authorization API](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview) instead of signin to authorize a user using Oauth2.

Comment: But I don't want to use any API I just want to keep the user authenticated even after that 1 hr. In that case I should use " Google Identity Services authorization API" ?

Comment: Then the issue is your cookie is probably expiring this has nothing to do with a refresh token, that's only used for offline access with Oauth2 not sign-in.

Answer (score 0):

You were not following the good tutorial it took me time too to find it

if you want a refresh token you need to use the server side way.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#node.js